# How to match Nullable String variable with its corresponding Enum value in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, exception, enums, sonarqube

I'll try to simplify the context. I have to improve that kind of code.

Please consider this enum :

```
public enum ErrorColor {
    
    YELLOW_VALUE_IS_MISSING("The value for field yellow is missing"),
    RED_VALUE_IS_MISSING("The value for field red is missing"),
    BLUE_VALUE_IS_MISSING("The value for field blue is missing"),
    GREEN_VALUE_IS_MISSING("The value for field green is missing"),
    PURPLE_VALUE_IS_MISSING("The value for field purple is missing");
    
    ErrorColor(String message) {this.message = message;}
    
    private String message;
    
    public String getMessage() {return message;}
}
```

Now its membered are used in another class:

```
private String defineColorLevel(String color, String yellow, 
                                String red, String blue, String green, 
                                String purple) throws Exception {
    switch(color){
        case "yellow" : {
            if (yellow == null)
                throw new Exception(ErrorColor.YELLOW_VALUE_IS_MISSING.getMessage());
            return yellow;
        }
        case "red" : {
            if (red == null)
                throw new Exception(ErrorColor.RED_VALUE_IS_MISSING.getMessage());
            return red;
        }
        case "blue" : {
            if (blue == null)
                throw new Exception(ErrorColor.BLUE_VALUE_IS_MISSING.getMessage());
            return blue;
        }
        case "green" : {
            if (green == null)
                throw new Exception(ErrorColor.GREEN_VALUE_IS_MISSING.getMessage());
            return green;
        }
        case "purple" : {
            if (purple== null)
                throw new Exception(ErrorColor.PURPLE_VALUE_IS_MISSING.getMessage());
            return purple;
        }
        default: throw new Exception("UnexpectedError");
    }
}
```

Actually, I have more than 15 cases with `if`-statements like these one and Sonar is not happy at all...

Could you please suggest a way to avoid this redundancy?

I've tried a method similar to:

```
private String throwErrorIfValueIsNullOrReturnIt(String value) {
    if (value == null)
        throw new Exception(Error.colorIsMissing(value));
    
    return value;
}
```

with the corresponding method in the enum to build the message but...  When value is `null` I can't use it to match with the corresponding missing input, neither to build the message.

And obviously, I can't use the name of the `String` variable. Can I fix that, or should I let Sonar cry?

Comment: Why does defineColorLevel have such arguments? Why all the strings yellow, red, and so on, if only one of them is ever used? Why color isn't an enum itself, but a string?

Answer (score 1):

## Use the power of Objects

Basically you need to combine the type of color `"yellow"`, `"red"`, `"blue"`, etc. and its `value` in order to avoid redundant logic.

For that, you can define a class or a Java 16 [record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html). I'll go with the latter option:

```
public record ColorValue(String value, ColorType type) {}
```

Where `ColorType` is your *enum*. Yes, you can the same enum to **classify** the types of colors and hold the error message. Therefore `ColorType` is more descriptive name.

```
public enum ColorType {
    
    YELLOW("The value for field yellow is missing"),
    RED("The value for field red is missing"),
    BLUE("The value for field blue is missing"),
    ... etc.

    // the rest code without changes
}
```

And your method that responsible for performing validation might look like this:

```
private String throwErrorIfValueIsNullOrReturnIt(ColorValue color) throws MyException {
    if (color.value() == null)
        throw new MyException(color.type().getMessage());
    
    return color.value();
}
```

**Note:** avoid using `Exception` type, try to use the most specific exception subtypes suitable for your case, or create a custom exception.

Comment: Thanks you also. I think with both or yours answer I could perform something good. :)

I'll keep you posted here.

Best

Answer (score 1):

The error messages differ only in color name. I would create a function to build the error message dynamically:

```
public class ErrorMessageBuilder implements Function<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String apply(String colorName) {
        return String.format("The value for field %s is missing", colorName);
    }
}
```

You can cache the function somewhere appropriate, it is stateless. Then simplify `defineColorLevel` to have only 2 parameters, `color` and `value`.

```
private String defineColorLevel(String color, String value) throws Exception {
    ErrorMessageBuilder errorMessageBuilder = new ErrorMessageBuilder();
    //validate color somehow, if needed at all
    if (value == null) {
        throw new Exception(errorMessageBuilder.apply(color));
    }
    return value;
}
```

Additionally, to guard against invalid colors, you can define an `enum` with valid ones, or a `Set`, or something else depending on exact use case.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

As I said, I tried to simplify the context. Colors are just a simpler model.
I need all arguments to define final colors.
Imagine values are a 3 letters combination and I need all of these several times (I am in a loop) to get final result with expected entry.
By the way, I 'll have a look and test this approach in my context. Thanks :-)